# Recaptcha getting Connection refused from RoR user form

Tags: ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2, recaptcha

I am trying to add reCaptcha to my user create form. But I am running into some errors.

Error Im seeing in my logs

```
 Nov 22 11:11:28 miningmonitor app/web.2: Recaptcha::RecaptchaError (Connection refused - connect(2))
 Nov 22 11:11:28 miningmonitor app/web.2:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in block in create
 Nov 22 11:11:28 miningmonitor app/web.2:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:26:in create
```

Here is my Form Code

```
     <%= form_for(@user) do |u| %>
        <%= render 'shared/user_error_msg' %>

        <%= u.label :name %>
        <%= u.text_field :name %>

        <%= u.label :email %>
        <%= u.text_field :email %>

        <%= u.label :coins, "Number of coins in your wallet(ex 4.5)" %>
        <%= u.text_field :coins %>

        <%= u.label :password %>
        <%= u.password_field :password %>

        <%= u.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= recaptcha_tags %>

        <%= u.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Now the user controller code for create

```
    def create
    @user= User.new(params[:user])
    @user.name.strip!
    respond_to do |format|
     if(verify_recaptcha(:model => @user))
       if @user.save
          sign_in(@user)
          format.html { redirect_to(@user, flash[:success] = "Welcome to Miners Canary!") }
       else
          format.html { render 'new' }
       end
     else
          flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
          format.html { redirect_to(root_path, flash[:error] = "Please retry the reCaptcha Verification") }
     end
    end
end
```

In my config/initializers/recaptcha.rb

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key = 'publickey'
  config.private_key = 'privatekey'
  config.use_ssl_by_default
  config.proxy= 'https://miningmonitor.herokuapp.com:8080'
end
```

I am actually seeing the reCaptcha box on my screen. But when I try to sign up I get the errors above. in my config file I gave the url as my base url not the exact url to the sign up page. could that be a problem? Could also be setting up reCaptcha incorrectly. I was trying to follow this [ambethia / recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) guide on github. I wish he had a few more examples.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code working doing t the following steps my user controller looked like so

```
    def create
    @user= User.new(params[:user])
    @user.name.strip!
    if(verify_recaptcha(model: @user, message: "Error with reCaptcha!", private_key: ENV['RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY'], timeout: 10) && @user.save)
          sign_in(@user)
          flash[:success] = "Welcome to Miners Canary"
          redirect_to @user
    else
          flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
          render 'new'
    end
end
```

My user form looks like so

```
        <%= form_for(@user) do |u| %>
        <%= render 'shared/user_error_msg' %>

        <%= u.label :name %>
        <%= u.text_field :name %>

        <%= u.label :email %>
        <%= u.text_field :email %>

        <%= u.label :password %>
        <%= u.password_field :password %>

        <%= u.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
        <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= recaptcha_tags display: { ssl: true, theme: 'clean' , tabindex: 1, public_key: ENV['RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY'] }%>

        <%= u.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Then to get it working with heroku I did these two commands

`heroku config:set RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'xxxxcxxxxxxxx'`

`heroku config:set RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'xxxxcxxxxxxxx'`